# Opening Excel File in Access does not bring up file on screen

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, office365

I am using Access 365, Excel 365, and Windows 10

I am using the following code to open and view an Excel file through MS Access:

```
Public Function fOpenWorkbook(pstrPath As String) As Boolean
Dim lboolOpenWorkbook As Boolean

    Set xlApp = excel.Application
    Set wbWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pstrPath)
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.WindowState = xlMaximized
    
    lboolOpenWorkbook = True
    
ExitOpenWorkbook:
    fOpenWorkbook = lboolOpenWorkbook
    Exit Function
    
ErrOpenWorkbook:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error in fOpenWorkbook"
    Resume ExitOpenWorkbook
    
End Function
```

When I execute this function on a file that has not been previous opened in the access session, the excel icon flashes orange on the taskbar instead of automatically opening.  Afterward, if I execute the function, the file opens automatically without my having to click on the excel icon.

Comment: As I indicate in your other thread https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=81939, cannot replicate issue. But I am using Access 2010.

Comment: I went ahead and posted a zip file of a database exhibiting similar behavior on two computers running access 365 and Excel 365 on Windows 10, on the other thread.  I really appreciate how helpful they have been over there. Thanks.

Comment: could not replicate in Access 2016

Comment: As a guess, try `Set xlApp=New Excel.Application` to create a new instance of Excel.

Comment: Applecore 5, tried your suggestion. Did not fix problem, though you are correct in saying that should have been the way it was coded.

Comment: Just noticed something weird but reproducible.  If, after opening the app but before attempting to open an excel file through it, I open the vba coding window and then close it, the excel file then displays on the screen like it should . I don't have to make any change to the code, just open and close the VBA screen.

Comment: Also, if I close the app, the excel file is right behind it, fully open and maximized.  So it appears the problem is that the excel window, when opened, does not go to the front.

Comment: Just tried it on more orthodox databases, with no user-defined properties in the database, and also with a table as a source for the form. No change.  It is though I need something to bring the excel window to the front after it opens.